# Replace space with underscore using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some help, I have a a txt file with spaces between words, I want to replace the space with underscore.

```
fileHandler = open('nog_rename_update.txt')
for eachline in fileHandler:
    new_name = fileHandler.replace("      ","_")
print(new_name)
```

That's my code but it keeps throwing error messages

> new_name = fileHandler.replace("      ","_")
> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

[example files that I want to remove space and add underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRj1y.png)

Comment: You need to read the contents of the file. `fileHandler.read()`

Comment: What do you think `eachline` should be used for?

Comment: `fileHandler.replace` should be `eachlist.replace`. I'm voting to close this as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This opens the files, reads line by line, splits the line into two parts, and combines the two parts with an underscore. I stored it in a list that you can use to do your next step.

```
with open('nog_rename_update.txt') as f:

    new_list = []

    for line in f:
        # split the line
        split = line.split()
        new_list.append(split[0]+"_"+split[1])

# print the list to see results
print(new_list)

#
# add code to loop through the new list and to write to a file
#
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic approach that should work for you:

```
teststring = 'hello world     this is just a   test. don\'t mind me 123.'

# replace multiple spaces with one space
while '  ' in teststring:
    teststring = teststring.replace('  ', ' ')

# replace space with underscore (_)
teststring = teststring.replace(' ', '_')

print(teststring)
assert teststring == "hello_world_this_is_just_a_test._don't_mind_me_123."  # True
```

Using a `file` example:

```
fname = 'mah_file.txt'
with open(fname) as in_file:
    contents = in_file.read()
    while '  ' in contents:
        contents = contents.replace('  ', ' ')
# write updated contents back to file
with open(fname, 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(contents.replace(' ', '_'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("test.txt", "r") 
text=f.read() 
f.close() 
f=open("testfile.txt", "w+") 
text2='' 
if ' ' in text: 
    text2 = text.replace(' ' , '_') 
    print(text2) 
    f.write(text2) 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this

```
fileHandler = open('nog_rename_update.txt').read()
new_name = fileHandler.replace(" ", "_")
print(new_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, less verbose solution. Simply use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```py
import re

file_name = r"D:\projects\playground\python\data\test.txt"

with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(re.sub("( )+", "_", line), end="")
```

---

And if you want to replace the spaces in your text file:

```py
import re

file_name = r"D:\projects\playground\python\data\test.txt"

lines = []

with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    lines = [
        re.sub("( )+", "_", line) for line in file.readlines()
    ]

with open(file_name, "w") as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Or use [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

```py
import re
import fileinput

file_name = r"D:\projects\playground\python\data\test.txt"

with fileinput.FileInput(file_name, inplace=True, backup=".bak") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(re.sub("( )+", "_", line), end="")
```